# jQuery Loop? Clone? Simply WHY?

Tags: xml, jquery, auto-increment, xml-database

**NEW VERSION (not new problem...)**

So, i got a "loop" problem with a `.click();` and a `.html();`.

Retrieve XML datas: **OK**

```
function afficher(NomPizz, Prix1, Prix2, Prix3) {//HERE IS MY CODE//});
```

Print them to screen: **OK**

```
$('#pricecontainer').show(); //Display my container and put values in with .html();
$('#prix1').html('SOLO 1P<p id="p1" style="line-height:10px;">' + Prix1.toFixed(2) + '</p>');
$('#prix2').html('MAXI 2P<p id="p2" style="line-height:10px;">' + Prix2.toFixed(2) + '</p>');
$('#prix3').html('SUPER 4P<p id="p3" style="line-height:10px;">' + Prix3.toFixed(2) + '</p>');​
```

Append value to other div when clicked: **OK** but **NOT**

Everithing works... ONCE ! When I click more times, the value "clone" itself.

**So, if I click one time: 1 Items i added.**

*I got: **1 OK***

**Two times click.**

*I got **3**, The previous one and **TWO MORE** !*

**Three times click.**

*I got **6**, The three previous and **THRE MORE** !*

Etc... Etc...

I Put this code **INTO** my `function afficher();` The only one solution i've found... BAD one !

```
$("clickedItemId").click(function() {
    var Figure = $(this).find('p').html();
    totalArea.value += '+' + Figure;
    var Screen = totalArea.value.replace(/'/g, ' ');
    var result = eval(Screen);
    totalArea.value = result;
    var $newItem = "<span style='float:left'>1 " + NomPizz.toUpperCase() + "</span><span style='float:right'>" + Figure + "</span><br/>";
    $('<div><div>').html($newItem).appendTo(RecapTick);
    Display2.value = "TOTAL (EUR): " + totalArea.value;
    $('#pricecontainer').hide();
});​
```

So, the ENTIRE code of my `function afficher();` will be:

```
function afficher(NomPizz, Prix1, Prix2, Prix3) {
    var totalArea = document.getElementById('totalArea');
    var Display2 = document.getElementById('Display2');
    var RecapTick = document.getElementById('MidTiTx');
    $('#pricecontainer').show();
    $('#prix1').html('SOLO 1P<p id="p1" style="line-height:10px;">' + Prix1.toFixed(2) + '</p>');
    $('#prix2').html('MAXI 2P<p id="p2" style="line-height:10px;">' + Prix2.toFixed(2) + '</p>');
    $('#prix3').html('SUPER 4P<p id="p3" style="line-height:10px;">' + Prix3.toFixed(2) + '</p>');
    //BUG HERRERRERERERERER
    $("clickedItemId").click(function() {
        var Figure = $(this).find('p').html();
        totalArea.value += '+' + Figure;
        var Screen = totalArea.value.replace(/'/g, ' ');
        var result = eval(Screen);
        totalArea.value = result;
        var $newItem = "<span style='float:left'>1 " + NomPizz.toUpperCase() + "</span><span style='float:right'>" + Figure + "</span><br/>";
        $('<div><div>').html($newItem).appendTo(RecapTick);
        Display2.value = "TOTAL (EUR): " + totalArea.value;
        $('#pricecontainer').hide();
    });
};​
```

---

---

PS I LIVE HERE THE OLD VERSION OF THE POST (Same pb with other code):

> So, my prolem is the following:
>
> [**LIVE DEMO**][1]
>
> **EDIT:** [**DOWNLOAD SOURCE**][2]
>
> It's a simple cart that retrieves the list of products from a xml
>   file. **This part works !**
>
> When they are clicked, the products added to the list below, but when
>   you click repeatedly on the same, the total of these should be added
>   ... **This is where I get stuck !**
>
> I tried to change the line 62:
>
> ```
> tot = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.prow').html());
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> tot = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.prow').html()+1);
> ```
>
> But not working... I think the problem is that I am using.
>   **.click();** with **onclick=""** method ??? Or maybe because of bad "**var**" use ?
>
> Please someone enlighten me !
>
> **Here is my jsCode:**
>
> ```
> function calculate(){
>   var tot = 0;
>   jQuery(".totprice").each(function(e,b){
>       tot += parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
>   });
>   return jQuery("#amt").html("$"+tot);
> }
>
> function showprod(){
>   jQuery(".prod").each(function(e){
>       jQuery(this).delay(500*e).fadeIn('fast');
>   });
> }
>
> function clearcart(){
>   jQuery("#clear").live('click',function(){
>       jQuery(".tetew").fadeIn(4000,function(){
>           jQuery(this).remove();
>           calculate();
>       });
>   });
> }
>
> function delete_ajax(){
>   jQuery(".del").live('click',function(e){
>       var a = jQuery(this);
>       var p = a.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
>       if(p){
>           p.fadeOut('slow',function(){
>               jQuery(this).remove();
>               calculate();
>           });
>       }
>   });
> }
>
> function addtocart(){
> jQuery(".addtocart").click(function(e){
>       var getprod = jQuery(this).attr("prodid");
>       var getval  = jQuery(this).attr("prodval");
>
>       jQuery("#msg").fadeIn('slow');
>
>       jQuery.ajax({
>           type:'GET',
>           url:'db.xml',
>           dataType:'xml',
>           success: function(xml){
>               jQuery(xml).find('databases').each(function(){
>                   jQuery(this).find('prod').each(function(e){
>                   var db_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
>
>                   jQuery("#msg").fadeOut('slow');
>                       if(getprod == db_id){
>                           var cookies = 1;
>                           jQuery(".tetew").each(function(){
>                               var _this = jQuery(this);
>                               var _store = _this.find('.pstore');
>                               var ident = _this.find('.pqty');
>
>                               if(getprod == ident.text()){
>                                   var tot = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.prow').html()); //Put a +1 here won't work...
>                                   jQuery(this).find('.prow').html(tot);
>                                       var restot = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.prow').text()) * parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.price').text());
>                                       jQuery(this).find('.totprice').html(restot);
>                                   cookies = 0;
>                                   return false;
>                               }else{
>                                   cookies = 1;
>                               }
>                           });
>
>                           if(cookies == 1){
>
>                           var results = "<div class='tetew'>";
>                               results +="<table>";
>                               results +="<tr>";
>                               results +="<td class='pqty' style='display:none' valign='top'>" + jQuery(this).attr("id") + "</td>";
>                               results +="<td class='img' valign='top'><img src='" + jQuery(this).attr('img') + "' width='40' height='40' /></td>";
>                               results +="<td class='pstore' valign='top'>" + jQuery(this).text() + "</td>";               
>                               results +="<td class='prow' valign='top'>1</td>";                           
>                               results +="<td class='price' valign='top'>" + jQuery(this).attr('price') + "</td>";                     
>                               results +="<td class='totprice' valign='top'>" + jQuery(this).attr('price') + "</td>";
>                               results +="<td  valign='top'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='del'>Delete</a></td>";
>                               results +="</tr>";
>                               results +="</table>";
>                               results +="</div>";
>                           }
>
>                           jQuery(".tetew:eq("+e+")").hide().fadeIn('fast');
>                               jQuery("#addto").append(results);
>                               calculate();
>                           return false;
>                       }
>                   });
>
>               }); 
>           }
>       });
>
>   });
> }
>
>  function loadXMLdb() {
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "GET",
>             url: "db.xml",
>             dataType: "xml",
>             success: function(xml) {
>                 $(xml).find('prod').each(function() {
>                     var _Nom = jQuery(this).text();
>                     var Col1 = jQuery(this).attr('id');
>                     var Col2 = jQuery(this).attr('price');
>                     var Col3 = $(this).find('grand').text();
>                     $('<div class="prod" style="display:block;" onclick="addtocart();"></div>').html(_Nom + '<br /><img
> ```
>
> src="images/pizza.png">
> Ajouter').appendTo(".vprod");
>
> ```
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>
>     }
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
>   showprod();
>   clearcart();
>   addtocart();    
>   delete_ajax();
> loadXMLdb();
> });
> ```
>
> [1]: http://bzez.0fees.net/examples/jCart/   [2]:
>   http://bzez.0fees.net/examples/jCart/jCart.zip

Comment: Hi bZezz, I'll take a look at your code and try to help you.
I'll also suggest you write less, do more :)
You'll sometimes get a bit confused when your js codes starts to grow too much.

Comment: Hi ! 1st, thank you ! 2nd, I'll try to write less do more ;)

Comment: To test localy http://bzez.0fees.net/examples/jCart/jCart.zip ;)

Comment: thanks, no need to zip it up. I got the files on locally already. checking it up

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your cart will only reflect what is in the xml file, so you can only have 1 of each item in it.  I suggest that you look at your problem differently.

try something like this:

```
var cart = [];

var items = [
    {id:1, price:100, name:"Catch Arena"},
    {id:2, price:400, name:"Pepperonni"},
    {id:3, price:1400, name:"Fruits de Mer"},
    {id:4, price:1400, name:"Chickenita"},
];
```

then, add an item to the cart with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addToCart(0);">Add Catch Arena</a>
<a href="#" onclick="addToCart(1);">Add Pepperonni</a>
<a href="#" onclick="addToCart(2);">Add Fruits de Mer</a>
<a href="#" onclick="addToCart(3);">Add Chickenita</a>
```

the addToCart I've got here uses the index (zero based) of the array:

```
window.addToCart = function(idx) {
    cart.push(items[idx]);
    displayCart();
};
```

Now you've got a cart, you need to display it:

```
<div id="ShoppingCart">Your cart is empty</div>
<div id="total"></div>
...
window.displayCart = function() {
    var cartHtml = [];
    var cartTotal = 0;
    for (i=0; i<cart.length; i++) {
        cartHtml.push("<div>" + cart[i].name + ", " + cart[i].price + "</div>");
        cartTotal += cart[i].price;
    }
    $('#total').html(cartTotal);
    $('#ShoppingCart').html(cartHtml.join(''));
};
```

I've got this running in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R4rzC/

I wouldn't say this is best practice either, as the cart should probably synced with a backend database etc, but I dare say there is a reason why you're implementing a cart is js, probably for technical reasons!

Comment: Nice one ! But, I need XML database... Is this possible with your code to get the item IDs from an xml file ? And, can we add the ammount of "price" value ? Sry, i'm beginner !

Comment: When i want to get the total amount i got the same problem... http://jsfiddle.net/bZezzz/acUvL/

Comment: I made a small edit to the total code, try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6eFf/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a re-write of the javascript code. (sometimes this is really going to help you to get a clearer solution)

---

at this state it is quite confusing and hard to read/debug.
You'll probably have more bugs later on this way.

When I recreated locally and tried the loop, it is looping more than once.
And you aren't fully taking advantage of jQuery SELECTORs, please look it up
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I'll answer your ques tonight when I get home, and provide some more solution.
in the meantime, try to rewrite this if you can

Try to do it like this. putting product_ids in TR

```
var obj = $('#table tr#prod_id_2').find('.prow');

var new_qty = obj.html() * 1; //gets current qty
new_qty = new_qty + 1;

obj.html( new_qty );
```

Comment: Hello, did you had a chance to rewrite it? sometimes we need to rewrite codes if its getting confusing.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some sleeping hours I found a solution.

I created a new `function poster();` who retrieve clicked element info and called by `onclick="poster(NomPizz, Prix)"`.

Here is the working new code:

If someone have better idea i'll take !

```
function afficher(NomPizz, Prix1, Prix2, Prix3) {
            var totalArea = document.getElementById('totalArea');
            var Display2 = document.getElementById('Display2');
            $('#pricecontainer').show();   \\Added <div> above
            $('#prix1').html('<div onclick="poster(\''+NomPizz+'\','+Prix1+')">SOLO 1P '+Prix1.toFixed(2)+'</div>');
            $('#prix2').html('<div onclick="poster(\''+NomPizz+'\','+Prix2+')">MAXI 2P '+Prix2.toFixed(2)+'</div>');
            $('#prix3').html('<div onclick="poster(\''+NomPizz+'\','+Prix3+')">SUPER 4P '+Prix3.toFixed(2)+'</div>');
            };

//NEW FUNCTION
function poster(NomPizz, Prix) {
            var RecapTick = document.getElementById('MidTiTx');
            totalArea.value += '+'+ Prix;
            var Screen = totalArea.value.replace(/'/g, ' ');
            var result = eval(Screen);
            totalArea.value = result.toFixed(2);
            var $newItem = "<span style='float:left'>1 " + NomPizz.toUpperCase() + "</span><span style='float:right'>" + Prix.toFixed(2)+"</span><br/>";
            $('<div><div>').html($newItem).appendTo(RecapTick);
            Display2.value = "TOTAL (EUR): "+totalArea.value;
            $('#pricecontainer').hide();
};
```